# Logging in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, logging, system.diagnostics

Is there any logger to asp.net like the System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging used in WCF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is health monitoring: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650305.aspx.  It has a bunch of predefined events, plus you can create your own custom events for tracking purposes.

Comment: I actually need to log all requests and responses as is done in WCF, but the Health Monitoring is help me anyway

tanks everybody!

Comment: The Health Monitoring system is your best pick here, because it is the only system that directly supports getting information on a per request basis (through the `WebRequestEvent` class).

Comment: The .NET framework is integrated with it too; it will log key ASP.NET framework events that occur within the system too.  It's pretty powerful.

Answer (score 2):

You could use log4net for this... [log4net Website](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html)

Comment: Yes, log4net is very commonly used in .NET because of its flexibility and unobtrusiveness.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are actually asking for. There is [ASP.NET tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx) and [trace.axd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwh16c6c.aspx) handler to browsing traces.

Answer (score 1):

After having used it myself, I'd like to suggest [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/):

> ELMAH (Error Logging Modules and
>   Handlers) is an application-wide error
>   logging facility that is completely
>   pluggable. It can be dynamically added
>   to a running ASP.NET web application,
>   or even all ASP.NET web applications
>   on a machine, without any need for
>   re-compilation or re-deployment.